# Data is not showing in view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I am new to Laravel and I am using Laravel 9. I am creating a migraine diary web app. I managed to create a custom log in and register system and created a page to display the diary entries and a diary entry form. Currently that page shows the username and user id with a couple of other lines. For showing the diary entries, I am currently trying to show the diary date to get it working, once I can show the date, I should be able to show the rest.

However, after completing the form I am redirected to the diary page as intended but the date from the database is not showing. I checked tinker and the data is being stored and when I used ddd it seems that no data is being sent to the view so I suspect it is something to do with how I am passing data into the view

I currently have 2 controllers, one to handle get requests so as to control user authorisation (and post requests for log in and register) and the other for post requests not related to log in and registration.

The relationship between users and the diary is that a user can have many diary entries, while a diary can only have one user

this is what shows at the bottom of ddd()
[snip of bottom of ddd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STfUI.png)

routes (web.php)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthorisationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EntryController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('diary', [AuthorisationController::class, 'diary'])->name('diary');

Route::get('loginpage', [AuthorisationController::class, 'loginPage'])->name('loggingin');

Route::post('computeLogin', [AuthorisationController::class, 'completeLogin'])->name('login.custom');

Route::get('register', [AuthorisationController::class, 'registerPage'])->name('registerUser');

Route::post('computeRegister', [AuthorisationController::class, 'computeRegistration'])->name('register.compute');

Route::get('signout', [AuthorisationController::class, 'logOut'])->name('logout');

Route::get('/addDiary', [AuthorisationController::class, 'addDiary'])->name('addDiary');

Route::post('/addDiary/entry', [EntryController::class, 'addDiaryEntry'])->name('addDiaryEntry');
```

User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        
    ];

    public function diaries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Diary::class);
    }
}
```

Diary model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Diary extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'date',
        'user_id',
        'stress',
        'low_water_intake',
        'chocolate',
        'cheese',
        'yeast_goods',
        'yoghurt',
        'fruit',
        'nuts',
        'olives',
        'tomato',
        'soy',
        'vinegar',
        'medication',
        'comment'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Authorisation Controller

```
<?php

/*
    need to customise look
    check for other bugs
*/

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Diary;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthorisationController extends Controller
{
    # index
    public function loginPage()
    {
        return view('auth.loginpage');
    }

    # customLogin
    public function completeLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $successful = 'Welcome User!';
        $failedLogin = 'Error! Entered details are not valid, please try again or register an account!';

        # diary
        $verifications = $request->only('username', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($verifications)) {
            return redirect('diary')->with('success', $successful);
        }

        return redirect('loginpage')->with('failed', $failedLogin);
    }

    # registration
    public function registerPage()
    {
        return view('auth.registerpage');
    }

    public function computeRegistration(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'password1' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);


        $info = $request->all();

        if($info['password'] == $info['password1']){
            User::create([
                'username' => $info['username'],
                'password' => Hash::make($info['password'])
            ]);

            $successRegistration = 'You have created an account!';

            $verifications = $request->only('username', 'password');
            if (Auth::attempt($verifications)) {
                return redirect('diary')->with('successReg', $successRegistration);
            }
            
        } else {
            $notMatching = 'Passwords do not match';
            return redirect('register')->with('notMatching', $notMatching);
        }
        
    }

    public function diary(User $user){
        if(Auth::check()){

            ddd('wont show data', $user->diaries);
            $data = $user->diaries->all();
            return view('diary', [
                'diaries' => $data,
            ]);
        }

        $noAccess = 'You are not signed in, either sign in or register!';
        
        return redirect('loginpage')->with('noAccess', $noAccess);
    }

    public function addDiary()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return view('addDiary');
        }

        $noAccess = 'You are not signed in, either sign in or register!';
        
        return redirect('loginpage')->with('noAccess', $noAccess);
    }

    public function logOut(){
        Session::flush();
        Auth::logout();

        $loggedOut = 'You have logged out, want to log back in?';

        return redirect('loginpage')->with('loggedOut', $loggedOut);
    }
}
```

Entry Controller (this controls posts not related to log in and register)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Diary;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class EntryController extends Controller
{
    public function addDiaryEntry(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'date' => 'required',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        $data = $request->all();
        $diaryEntry = new Diary();
        $diaryEntry->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $diaryEntry->date = $data['date'];
        $diaryEntry->stress = $data['stress'];
        $diaryEntry->low_water_intake = $data['dehydrated'];
        $diaryEntry->chocolate = $data['chocolate'];
        $diaryEntry->cheese = $data['cheese'];
        $diaryEntry->yeast_goods = $data['yeast'];
        $diaryEntry->yoghurt = $data['yoghurt'];
        $diaryEntry->fruit = $data['fruit'];
        $diaryEntry->nuts = $data['nuts'];
        $diaryEntry->olives = $data['olives'];
        $diaryEntry->tomato = $data['tomato'];
        $diaryEntry->soy = $data['soy'];
        $diaryEntry->vinegar = $data['vinegar'];
        $diaryEntry->medication = $data['takenMeds'];
        $diaryEntry->comment = $data['comment'];

        if (!$diaryEntry->save())
        {
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        $diaryEntry->save();

        return redirect('diary');
    }

    
}
```

dairy.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('maincontent')
    <main>
        @foreach ($diaries as $diary)
            <div class="container">
                <h4>
                    Date
                </h4>
                <p>
                    {{ $diary->date->toDateString() }}
                </p>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        <p>
            Welcome {{ auth()->user()->username }}!
        </p>
        <p>
            Welcome user with id {{ auth()->user()->id }}!
        </p>
        @if (session('success'))
            <small>
                {{ session('success') }}
            </small>
        @elseif (session('successReg'))
            <small>
                {{ session('successReg') }}
            </small>
        @endif
        <p style="margin:1em;">
            Success. 
        </p>
        <button>
           <a href="/addDiary">Add Diary Entry</a> 
        </button>
        
    </main>
@endsection
```

addDiary.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('maincontent')
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('addDiaryEntry') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label">Date</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input id="date" name="date" type="date" class="form-control" required="required">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Stressed</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="stress" id="stress" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Dehydrated</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="dehydrated" id="dehydrated" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Chocolate</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="chocolate" id="chocolate" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Cheese</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="cheese" id="cheese" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Yeast Products</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="yeast" id="yeast" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Yoghurt</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="yoghurt" id="yoghurt" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Citrus Fruits</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="fruit" id="fruit" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Nuts</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="nuts" id="nuts" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Olives</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="olives" id="olives" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Tomato</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="tomato" id="tomato" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Soy</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="soy" id="soy" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Vinegar</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                        <input name="vinegar" id="vinegar" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="takenMeds" class="col-4 col-form-label">Medication Taken</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <textarea id="takenMeds" name="takenMeds" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="comments" class="col-4 col-form-label">Comment</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                    <textarea id="comments" name="comment" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="offset-4 col-8">
                <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        
    </main>
@endsection
```

Comment: You can chain `->middleware('auth')` to the routes that required an authenticated user (so you can stop checking for authentication inside your functions). You can then gather the authenticated user data by using `auth()->user`, instead of trying to inject it.

Comment: 1. you are not logging in.  2. you don't pass ANY data to the view.  I suggest you step back and watch a few tutorials